# Pygame seems to "avoid" loop

Tags: python, events, pygame

I am just getting started with Pygame and I am currently trying out some basic movement functions.

I ran into a problem when trying to code my movement conditions into my object class rather than in the game loop.

My first attempt which works is as follow:

classes.py:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
class GameObject:
    def __init__(self, image, height, speed):
        self.speed = speed
        self.image = image
        self.pos = image.get_rect().move(0, height) #initial placement

    def move_south(self):
        self.pos = self.pos.move(0, self.speed)
        if self.pos.right > 600:
            self.pos.left = 0

    def move_east(self):
        self.pos = self.pos.move(self.speed , 0)
        if self.pos.right > 600:
            self.pos.left = 0
```

main.py:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from classes import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
#Importing Chars
player = pygame.image.load('green_hunter_small.png').convert()
#player.set_alpha(100) #makes whole player transparent
player.set_colorkey((0,0,0)) #sets background colour to transparent

ennemi =  pygame.image.load('red_hunter_small.png').convert()
ennemi.set_colorkey((0,0,0))

background = pygame.image.load('grass_map_640x640.png').convert()
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
objects = []
objects.append(GameObject(player, 80, 0))
for x in range(2):      #create 2 objects
    o = GameObject(ennemi, x*40, 0)
    objects.append(o)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #setting up quit
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                for o in objects:
                    screen.blit(background, o.pos, o.pos) #erases players by bliting bg 
                for o in objects:
                    o.speed = 4
                    o.move_south() #moves player
                    o.speed = 0
                    screen.blit(o.image, o.pos) #draws player
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                for o in objects:
                    screen.blit(background, o.pos, o.pos) #erases players by bliting bg 
                for o in objects:
                    o.speed = 4
                    o.move_east() #moves player
                    o.speed = 0
                    screen.blit(o.image, o.pos) #draws player                    
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50)
```

My second attempt which didn't work was to dp:

classes.py:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

class GameObject:
    def __init__(self, image, height, speed):
        self.speed = speed
        self.image = image
        self.pos = image.get_rect().move(0, height) #initial placement

    def move_south(self):
        self.pos = self.pos.move(0, self.speed)
        if self.pos.right > 600:
            self.pos.left = 0

    def move_east(self):
        self.pos = self.pos.move(self.speed , 0)
        if self.pos.right > 600:
            self.pos.left = 0

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    screen.blit(background, self.pos, self.pos) #erases players by bliting bg 
                    self.speed = 4
                    self.move_south() #moves player
                    self.speed = 0
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    screen.blit(background, self.pos, self.pos) #erases players by bliting bg 
                    self.speed = 4
                    self.move_east() #moves player
                    self.speed = 0
                screen.blit(self.image, self.pos) #draws player
```

main.py:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from classes import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
#Importing Chars
player = pygame.image.load('green_hunter_small.png').convert()
#player.set_alpha(100) #makes whole player transparent
player.set_colorkey((0,0,0)) #sets background colour to transparent

ennemi =  pygame.image.load('red_hunter_small.png').convert()
ennemi.set_colorkey((0,0,0))

background = pygame.image.load('grass_map_640x640.png').convert()
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
objects = []
objects.append(GameObject(player, 80, 0))
for x in range(2):      #create 2 objects
    o = GameObject(ennemi, x*40, 0)
    objects.append(o)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #setting up quit
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for o in objects:
        o.move()        
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(50)
```

So it seems that the code struggles to go and check the event loop from the instance. The reason I wanted to code the movement as a method rather than straight in main was to save space and make it easier to add characters later on.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I think this is a good question with good attempts and assumptions. I'm on a train and can't solve this right now, but it's a good question especially for a "beginner"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have done a bit more work on it and thanks to the other comments understand it a bit better. I have changed my system to comparing my player's position to the mouse position and making the player move towards the click position. At the moment I am stuck because although my new system works I have to click a lot to get it to move all the way to the position of the click. Ideally I'd like it to keep moving towards the click position on its own.

Comment: @Sorade the need to click a lot is a seperate problem and should be [asked seperately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: It could do with breaking down a bit. Read [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't understand what you mean. This question is too complicated? The hypothetical one I told Sorade to ask?

Comment: @ppperry: I wasn't talking to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a race condition (to use the term really loosely).

The reason that your characters are not moving is that the first `pygame.event.get` call (when you are checking for a `QUIT` event) consumes all the `KEYDOWN` events that are on the queue. Then (unless you manage to press a key  while the first loop is running), there are no `KEYDOWN` events in the queue when the first `GameObject` checks for events. Diddo for all other `GameObjects`.

You need to handler all pygame events in one loop. Example code:

```
class GameObject():
    #rest of class
    def move(self,event):
        if event.key == K_DOWN:
             screen.blit(background, self.pos, self.pos) #erases players by bliting bg 
             self.speed = 4
             self.move_south() #moves player
             self.speed = 0
        #repeat for all other directions
        screen.blit(self.image, self.pos) #draws player
#initialize objects
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT: #handle quit event
         elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            for o in objects:
                o.move(event)
    #do non-eventhandling tasks.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it is very useful. I got it to work. I however have to pass "background" as an argument of my move(self, background) method for it to work. Otherwise I get the Error, global variable not defined error. Is there a way to bypass that or do I have to list all the variables used in the method as arguments ?

Comment: You don't have to list all the variables as arguments

Comment: I have changed the code a bit (I look for the mouse position instead and move towards it) but I get errors when I don't do that:

Comment: def move(self,event,mouse_pos, screen, background):
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if mouse_pos[1] > self.pos[1]:
                    screen.blit(background, self.pos, self.pos) #erases players by bliting bg 
                    self.speed = 1
                    self.move_south() #moves player
                if mouse_pos[0] > self.pos[0]:
                    screen.blit(background, self.pos, self.pos)  by bliting bg 
                    self.speed = 1
                    self.move_east() 
                screen.blit(self.image, self.pos)

Comment: @Sorade when you change your code like that, you shoudl add it to the question (with a heading like UPDATE:) instead of posting it in a comment.

Comment: Okay sorry about that I was looking for a way of formatting it nicely. I will edit the question.

Comment: The `NameError: global name 'background' is not defined` problem is also a seperate question that should be [asked seperately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Okay I've created a new question for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814328/error-global-variable-not-defined-when-importing-class