# Changed Variable in another module won't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm trying to have a changed variable affect another module. That other module doesn't seem to notice the change.

a.py:

```
import b

b.changeMyVar()
print(b.myVar["key"])
```

b.py:

```
myVar = {"key": "foo"}

def changeMyVar():
    myVar["key"] = "value"
```

What I expect (on running a.py):

```
value
```

What I get:

```
foo
```

How do I make this work? Why doesn't it work? Would things be different if `myVar` was a dictionary that is mutated by `changeMyVar` (both situations occur in my program)?

Note how I didn't write `from b import *`, which is evil as I understand.

Edit 1: As commenters pointed out, if `myVar` was an immutable object, this wouldn't work without `global myVar`. I changed the example to better reflect what I mean.

Edit 2:  I forgot to add `b.` However, my question remains unchanged. The variables is defined but runtime changes are not visible from the other module. I have again edited the code to clarify my problem.

Comment: This wouldn't even work at the same module level let alone across modules.

Comment: Functions define a scope...

Comment: WIth your new code, I'd expect you to get `NameError: name 'changeMyVar' is not defined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Global Variable not defined when importing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814328/error-global-variable-not-defined-when-importing-class) (yes, I know that's a pygame question, but it has the same problem manifesting)

Comment: `a` doesn't have a global named `myVar`; `b` does. After you call `changeMyVar`, you need to write `print(b.myVar["key"])` to see the effect. A function with free variables keeps a dict of its *module* global variables for such lookups to succeed.

Comment: In 'a.py', give explicit references: `b.changeMyVar` and `b.myVar`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I added `b.` in the example to boil down the problem.

Comment: With the code as currently written, I can't reproduce your issue. Are you sure that you're seeing "foo" rather than "value", and that the code you're running is _exactly_ as written in the question?

Answer (score 2):

`import b` does't import `myVar` or `changeMyVar` to the scope of a.py, it only defines the name `b` referring to the module.

So you have to use the name `b` to access `myVar` and `changeMyVar()` in a.py:

```
import b

b.changeMyVar()
print(b.myVar["key"])
```

Comment: Kind of. The whole `b` module gets imported, but the only name added to `a`'s namespace is `b`.